# Issues with printing a floating point number from user input in C

Tags: c

I feel the code should be executing properly for the  floating point number printout however it keeps printing a zero value for some reason. Hopefully you can point me in the right direction of my mistake. I need it to display 2 decimal places to show as a currency as you can see in my code snippet. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

double myNumber2;
printf("Guess how much I paid for my coffee this morning using the following format 1.65 which would represent $1 and 65 cents: ");
scanf("%.2f", &myNumber2);
printf("You guessed that I paid $%.2f for my coffee.\n", myNumber2);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work :-/  Still receiving $0.00 as print value

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and fix the warnings

Comment: Try 'scanf("%lf", &myNumber2);' and 'printf("You guessed that I paid $%.02f for my coffee.\n", myNumber2);'

Comment: never mind I needed to change  `double myNumber2;`  to `float myNumber2;`

Comment: Instead of changing "double" to "float", you could also have changed the "f" in scanf to "lf".

Comment: Thank you for your help m8, I'd select your answer but it seems I cannot select answers because I have less than 10 rep. Not sure why I'm getting down voted for this.... Anyway much appreciated. If I end of getting enough rep to select your answer I'll be sure to select yours then.

Comment: Whose comment are you referring to? The link provider by user "moooeeeep" or the comments I wrote? You cannot accept comments, only answers. Nobody has provided your question with a formal answer yet, but I am currently writing a more detailed one for one for you.

Comment: To you @AndreasWenzel

Comment: Sorry new to this site, still trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Tim I downvoted. It's nothing personal, but this Q has very little chance of being useful for someone else. If you compiled with warnings and included the warnings in the question, then someone with the same problem could find this question. But in the same way, if you google your warnings you will find several questions already asked that will help you.

Comment: @klutt My apologizes, I attempted to limit the code and the length of my question to as little as possible to make it very clear as to what I was needing and easier for the person to help me without going through tons of data to find a tiny issue. I figured that would be preferred.

Comment: @Tim And that's a very good thing to do. It's called creating a [mre]. Kudos for doing that.

Comment: But ALWAYS compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. Warnings is the compilers way of telling you that your code probably don't do what you think it does.

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot post my answer anymore, now that the question has been closed. So I will just make one further remark: Using scanf() without checking the return value can be dangerous, for the reasons described [here](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: Thanks for that link I will look through it. This is for a course as the link you sent suggested it most likely was.

Comment: Also, in my example, I wrote simply "f" instead of "lf" in the [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). In my experience, this works, but I am not sure if it is formally correct or if it would work on all platforms. Therefore, using "lf" may be safer (assuming the type being printed is double, not float). The documentation that I linked to says that "lf" should be used (even if printf seems to work with me without the "l"). When using scanf, the extra "l" is certainly necessary.